# What is the best way of storing last run date-time/ execution date-time for windows service?

Tags: datetime, windows-services

I have a windows service that runs every 1 hour. I would like to store the last run date-time so that I can check the value (last run date-time) every time the service runs.
This value is used as one of the parameter for stored procedure used by the service to get data.

Now, my question is what is the best/ideal way of storing this last run date value?

I can think of 3 ways:

1. Store it in a database table.
2. Store it in a text or XML file in the application folder (question here is: is it good to create a text
   file in application folder and update it every hour?).
3. Create a section in config file and update it every time service is executed.

Experts, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single service that needs to check the last time the process it executes was run to completion, I would store in as a user setting item.  If you are thinking that maybe you'll have many services that share this task, putting it a shared location (like a database) would be helpful--although, it should be easy to migrate the data from user setting to a database should you need to use multiple services.

I would avoid a custom XML or data file simply because there's already support for user (run-time) settings in .NET and Visual Studio.

**Update:**

If you want to use user settings, you can simply double-click the Settings in Solution Explorer (under Properties in a Project) or in the properties for a Project, select the Settings tab.  Add a value with a User Scope (probably of type `System.DateTime`.  And if you named `LastExecuted` it you would use code like the following to update the value:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.LastExecuted = DateTime.Now;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: When you say "User Setting Item" does that mean App.config file? Could you please post sample code?

Comment: Great solution @Peter but one more question. Where does it actually store the value? Will it be a problem if this service is being deployed on protection server which is not maintained by me?

Comment: Typically the user.config resides in the appdata folder.  e.g. `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\AppName\AppName\1.0.0.0`
  If roaming is enabled in Windows, this will be `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\1.0.0.0`

Comment: Well, I am still worried about loosing this file. I think I will go the database way.